# when you must avoid using MPI_COMM_WORLD?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

Can you give me some examples when you should not use MPI_COMM_WORLD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two cases: when you are writing multithreaded code or a library.

The reason is that the MPI communicator is part of the message matching context.  If you use `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in an MPI call from a library, and also from user code, you might match the wrong message.  Using special tags in the library code is brittle, since the user code might use the same tag.  It is much easier to just make a separate communicator.

The issue with multithreaded code is the same - message matching, except with even more opportunities for it to go wrong.  For example, if you use collective calls in multithreaded code there is no longer a tag to differentiate them, and undefined behavior will result.

Finally, removing the dependency on MPI_COMM_WORLD can make your code more modular.  For example, say you write a class for some calculation.  Later you might want to include this class in another program, but only carry out the calculation on a subset of the nodes.  If the class constructor takes a communicator a parameter, `MPI_Comm_dup`s it, and works with that - integration is easy.  If `MPI_COMM_WORLD` was hardcoded then some refactoring will be in order.

In C++ in particular you will likely encapsulate independent parts of the program in classes.  It might be beneficial to view these as mini-libraries and make them independent from each other, so that the code that uses them does not have to worry about how the combination might act.